# Possible "Traveling Salesman" function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am looking to solve a Traveling Salesman type problem using a matrix in order to find the minimum time between transitions. The matrix looks something like this:

```
A =  [inf 4 3 5; 
      1 inf 3 5;
      4 5 inf 3;
      6 7 1 inf]
```

The y-axis represents the "from" node and the x-axis represents the "to" node. I am trying to find the optimal time from node 1 to node 4. I was told that there is a Matlab function called "TravellingSalesman". Is that true, and if not, how would I go about solving this matrix?

Thanks!

Comment: I found something [here](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/tsp_brute/tsp_brute.html) and there is also some stuff on [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/index?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=traveling+salesman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an outline of the brute-force algorithm to solve TSP for paths from node `1` to node `n`:

```
C = inf
P = zeros(1,n-2)
for each permutation P of the nodes [2..n-1]
   // paths always start from node 1 and end on node n
   C = A(1,P(1)) + A(P(1),P(2)) + A(P(2),P(3)) + ... + 
       A(P(n-3),P(n-2)) + A(P(n-2),n)
   if C < minCost
      minCost = C
      minPath = P
   elseif C == minCost         // you only need this part if you want
      minPath = [minPath; P]   // ALL paths with the shortest distance
   end
end
```

Note that the first and last factors in the sum are different because you know beforehand what the first and last nodes are, so you don't have to include them in the permutations. So in the example given, with `n=4`, there are actually only `2!=2` possible paths.

The list of permutations can be precalculated using `perms(2:n-1)`, but that might involve storing a large matrix (`n! x n`). Or you can calculate the cost as you generate each permutation. There are several files on the Mathworks file exchange with names like `nextPerm` that should work for you. Either way, as `n` grows you're going to be generating a very large number of permutations and your calculations will take a very long time.